# need explanation about rest PUT method

Tags: java, spring, rest, put

here is some controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/put/{login}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody User putUser(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable String login){
        return user;
    }
```

when i send this request

```
{"login":"ale"}
```

to this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/Application/rest/put/termination
```

i receive normal response like this:

```
{"login":"ale","password":"password","email":"email"}
```

**My question:** why in controller must be @PathVariable login(at least it is in all tutorials) instead just static URL, and what the reason be here it?

Comment: i understood, put have to be used on only existing mapping and only for update entity ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your question is not quite accurate. It is not a *must* to include `@PathVariable` inside the controller method. You can use static URL whenever you like.

Secondly, it is not a *must* to put `@PathVariable` for REST, but a **standard**. The standard is trying to map common *CRUD* operations with common HTTP verbs (*POST, GET, PUT, DELETE*), and the URL would typically include the resource name and resource ID. Usually, `@PathVariable` represents resource ID in REST-standard URL.

An example of such URL would be `/user/{user_id}`, where `user` is the resource name and `user_id` would be the resource id.

So, lastly, by looking at the code you posted. That `@PathVariable String login` does not really align with the REST standard. As in your example URL,

```
http://localhost:8080/Application/rest/put/termination
```

That means `login = termination`, which is obviously nothing related to REST.

Comment: useful answer, but what if my user haven't id field and haven't id column in database?

Comment: Then REST does not fit your purpose.